# ¿Cómo salvar un modelo de tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, inteligencia-artificial, lstm

Tengo el siguiente modelo implementado en tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class DvLSTM(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(DvLSTM, self).__init__(name='BaseLineModel')
    #self.lstm = HandWrittenLSTM(input_shape=50)

    self.lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(504, name='BasicLSTM')
    self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='linear')
    self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    self.first_shape = -1
    self.cond = True

  def call(self, input, training=True):
    x = tf.expand_dims(input, axis=2)
    if self.cond:
      self.cond = False
      self.first_shape = tf.shape(input)
    y = self.lstm(x)
    return y

  def train_step(self, input):
    x, y = input
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      y_pred = self(x)
      y_pred = self.dense(y_pred)
      loss = self.compiled_loss(tf.one_hot(y, 30), y_pred)


    # Compute gradients
    trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
    # Update weights
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
    # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(tf.one_hot(y, 30), y_pred)
    # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
    return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}

  def test_step(self, input):
    x, y = input
    y_pred = self(x)
    y_pred = self.dense(y_pred)
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(tf.one_hot(y, 30),y_pred)
    return {self.metrics[1].name: self.metrics[1].result()}
```

A continuación se muestran las funciones que utilicé para la optimización y el cálculo de las pérdidas, además de las configuraciones del entrenamiento

```
model = DvLSTM()
adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
cat_cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(loss=cat_cross_entropy, optimizer= adam, metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    train_ds.shuffle(188, reshuffle_each_iteration=True),
    validation_data=validation_ds.shuffle(188, reshuffle_each_iteration=True), 
    verbose=1, epochs=1, batch_size=50)
```

Al guardarlo como se muestra en el siguiente codigo

```
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/SdLSTM'
model.save(path)
```

Muestra este mensaje de error

```
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as dense_10_layer_call_fn, dense_10_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, lstm_cell_16_layer_call_fn, lstm_cell_16_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, dense_10_layer_call_fn while saving (showing 5 of 10). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/drive/MyDrive/SdLSTM/assets
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/drive/MyDrive/SdLSTM/assets
WARNING:absl:<keras.layers.recurrent.LSTMCell object at 0x7f3b9e8be310> has the same name 'LSTMCell' as a built-in Keras object. Consider renaming <class 'keras.layers.recurrent.LSTMCell'> to avoid naming conflicts when loading with `tf.keras.models.load_model`. If renaming is not possible, pass the object in the `custom_objects` parameter of the load function.
```

Quisiera saber la causa de estos errores y como podría solucionarlos. Saludos

Comment: No son errores sino advertencias. Pese a ellas seguramente te ha guardado el modelo. Compruébalo, y comprueba si puedes cargarlo desde otro script y aplicarlo. Si eso funciona, no hay necesidad de "arreglar" nada. Y si no, me temo que mal arreglo tendrá pues las funciones y clases a las que se refiere el warning son cosas internas de tensorflow. Sería una _issue_ a reportar (quizás incluso esté arreglada en otra versión de la librería)

Comment: Ya lo comprobé, cuando cargo el modelo desde el fichero me da error al usar el método model.evaluate() que si funciona en el modelo antes de guardarlo. Pero bueno al parecer es un issue. Gracias por tu tiempo